# Xcode how to NSLog a JSON

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nslog, uidevice

Is there any way to get NSLog to print out an entire JSON file. I am currently saying

```
NSString *deviceInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                        [[UIDevice currentDevice]model], [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]];
NSDictionary *json = [deviceInfo JSONValue];
NSLog(@"json file = %@", json);
```

And it is printing out "json file = (null)"

Thanks
Clinton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you’re misunderstanding what JSON is for. The string you’re passing to `-JSONValue` isn’t a valid JSON string, so it’s returning nil. You might as well just construct the dictionary yourself:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSDictionary *deviceInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[device model], @"deviceModel", [device systemVersion], @"deviceSystemVersion", nil];
```

Then if you want the JSON string representation of the object (for sending to your server, for instance):

```
NSString *jsonDeviceInfo = [deviceInfo JSONRepresentation];
```

Comment: thank you that is working quite well. It is currently printing out this `{"deviceModel":"iPod touch","deviceSystemVersion":"4.3.5"}` and if I want to have multiple of the blocks and something on the outside of each like `"hardware":{"deviceModel":"iPod touch"} "os":{"deviceSystemVersion":"4.3.5"}` How would I do that.

Comment: Just nest the dictionaries. `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:someDictionary, @"someKey", someOtherDictionary, @"someOtherKey", nil]`

Comment: Yes that worked. One more thing tho. I can't seem to be able to change the order in the NSDictionary. I have `NSDictionary *fullJSON = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: hardware, @"hw", os, @"os", nil];` but it is printing out `{"os":{"ver":"4.3.5"},"hw":{"model":"iPod touch"}}` I dont think its necessary but it would be nice if I were able to make hardware come first.

Comment: The order of the keys in a dictionary isn’t really defined. Wherever you’re using that data, just pull the values out in the order you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your code works correctly? Your NSDictionary seems to be nil ...

Could you please post the implementation of JSONValue?

If an object doesn't print as expected you can always override the `-(NSString *) description` method through an extension and it will print how you've specified :)

Comment: I tried `NSLog(@"json file = %@", [json description]);` and I still received (null). Also there seems to be an error with the JSONValue. It says `-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x1cc3c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"` I don't know what you mean by the implementation of JSONValue.

Comment: NSString doesn't implement a method called JSONValue afaik, so you must've implemented it yourself? Which code do you use in this method?

Comment: JSONValue is from the JSON library. It looks like this `- (id)JSONValue
{
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    id repr = [jsonParser objectWithString:self];
    if (!repr)
        NSLog(@"-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: %@", [jsonParser errorTrace]);
    [jsonParser release];
    return repr;
}`