# How can we format or convert the Xcode log or print in JSON format?

Tags: json, xcode

Is there a way we can convert the Xcode print or log in the JSON format?
Currently if we print or log a dictionary or JSON, it shows like this:

```
data =     {
        currentCity = Mycity;
        friends = 4;
        images =         (
        );
        suggestions = 3;
    }
```

but if we want Xcode to print in the proper json format like this, what can we do?

```
"data": {
    "currentCity": "Mycity",
    "friends": 4,
    "images": [],
    "suggestions": 3
  }
```

Or is there any tool available that converts the Xcode print or log in pretty JSON format?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098270/8385972)

Comment: Do you have used Alamofire for REST API?
Please try pod:
https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger
Config:
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NetworkActivityLogger.shared.level = .debug
    NetworkActivityLogger.shared.startLogging()

    return true
}`

Comment: Why do you have an XCode print at first? What about writing directly a JSON String? What's your use? You just need to do `let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myDict, options:[.prettyPrinted]) let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8); print("jsonString: \(jsonString)")`?

Comment: You are not printing or logging JSON. You are printing/logging an `NSArray/NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simpler way in swift
use need to use this pod: [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Install the pod and use the following code:

```
import SwiftyJSON

func printInJSON {
    var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
    dictionary["build_number"] = "1.0"
    dictionary["data"] = "Print in JSON format on iOS xcode"

    // SwiftyJson magic
    let json = JSON(dictionary)
    print(json)
}

Output:
{
   "build_number" : "1.0"
   "data" : "Print in JSON format on iOS xcode"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing an object that is coming back from a network request, I find using Charles Proxy is usually easier. It will format it in JSON and it is a very useful debugging tool.

Answer (score -3):

You may try in console:

```
po print(data)
```

It usually helped me